# unable to setup psuedo distributed hadoop cluster

Tags: hadoop

I am using centos 7. Downloaded and untarred hadoop 2.4.0 and followed the instruction as per the link [Hadoop 2.4.0 setup](http://hadoop.apache.org/docs/r2.4.0/hadoop-project-dist/hadoop-common/SingleNodeSetup.html)

Ran the following command.
./hdfs namenode -format
Got this error :
Error: Could not find or load main class org.apache.hadoop.hdfs.server.namenode.NameNode
I see a number of posts with the same error with no accepted answers and I have tried them all without any luck.

Comment: I believe lot of people have experienced the same problem. I am yet to see a single reliable answer for this problem. Please help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I followed the link [Setup hadoop 2.4.0](http://tecadmin.net/setup-hadoop-2-4-single-node-cluster-on-linux/)

and I was able to get over the error message.
Seems like the documentation on hadoop site is not complete.

Answer (score 0):

This error can occur if the necessary jarfiles are not readable by the user running the "./hdfs" command or are misplaced so that they can't be found by hadoop/libexec/hadoop-config.sh.

Check the permissions on the jarfiles under: `hadoop-install/share/hadoop/*`:

```
ls -l share/hadoop/*/*.jar
```

and if necessary, chmod them as the owner of the respective files to ensure they're readable. Something like `chmod 644` should be sufficient to at least check if that fixes the initial problem. For the more permanent fix, you'll likely want to run the hadoop commands as the same user that owns all the files.

Comment: I am  the owner of the files and all permissions for all JARs under <install-dir>/share/hadoop is set to 644. I am not sure what you mean by files may be misplaced. I am on centos 7 and have tried mutliple releases of hadoop and directory structure created seems correct and in line with installation steps.